# how to check if a discord bot is in the same channel as a user in discord.js v13?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to be able to check if the bot is currently in the same voice channel as the user who sent the triggering command

Answer (score 0):

Get the voice channel IDs of both the bot and the user, and compare them

```js
if (!message.member.voice.channel && message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
  // bot is in VC, but member is not
} else if (message.member.voice.channel && !message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
  // member is in VC, but bot is not
} else if (!message.member.voice.channel && !message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
  // both bot and member are not in VC
} else if (message.member.voice.channel.id === message.guild.me.voice.channel.id) {
  // In same channel
}
```